# How to send an array from client side javascript to node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, node.js, data-transfer

I have a post tags functionality for my website:
[Tag functionallity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3tlF.jpg).
have a look at this code, I grab that tags with javascript and save them into tags array:

```
var formNewPost = $("#formNewPost");
formNewPost.on("submit", function (event) {
  var tagElements = $("span.tag span");
  var tags = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tagElements.length; i++) {
    var text = document.querySelectorAll("span.tag span")[i].innerText;
    text = text.trim();
    tags.push(text);
  }
});
```

now I have my suitable array, now I wanna save that into my mongoDB database. my node js code:

```
  var title = req.body.title;
  var tags =  // I want that array from client side to be here
  var type = req.body.type;
  var body = req.body.body;
  var author = req.body.author;

  var newPost = {title, author, tags, type, body, author};

  Post.create(newPost, function (err, newPost) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash('error', 'An error occurred, please try again.');
      res.redirect('/posts/new');
    } else {
      req.flash('success', 'Post created successfully.');
      res.redirect('/posts');
    }
  });
```

But how can I do that?
I tried this code but it is not working at all:

```
tags.push(text);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/posts',
        data: { tags : tags },
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("success!");
        }
    });
```

then grab that data with express:

```
  var tags = req.body.tags; // AN ARRAY FROM JAVASCRIPT
```

But it is not working at all, what is the problem?

Comment: you have to send the data from your html page with an AJAX query to nodejs by creating a server ( use express for example ) and  web service who will get the data and write then into mongodb

A little exemple :  

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm

Comment: Joseph Node js is a server side implementation, like java or c#. You have to make an ajax request as @Alainlb mentioned. One of the benefits of using node js is that since is JS it support Javascript Object Notation (JSON) by default, so no need for serialization.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I send just an array with ajax to my server(in this case node js)?

Comment: You need to use ajax if you are waiting for a return data from the server otherwise just send your array in a get or a post

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what am I doing, but it doesn't work. see that?

Comment: which bit isn't working? there's barely any information here. first i would cnosole.log every step of the way. Is the tags making it into the array, is anything getting to your express server etc